# Help needed on identifying parts and assemblies, yellow Technic pieces and teal lobster?

Tags: part-identification

I have the following pieces and sub-assemblies and would like some help determining what sets they are from.  The green/turquoise crab has a 993-1 mark on it, but have not been able to find anything about it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right assembly is from set [8225 - Road Rally V](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8225-1%20%E2%80%9C8225) from 1995.

[image]

The middle assembly is likely a MOC, there is no set that I can find which includes this build with the 2 1x4x2 Fence pieces with only 2 studs in either Dark Gray or Dark Bluish Gray.

The crab-like item on the left is from set [8268 - Scorpion Attack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8268-1), also from 1995.

[image]

Comment: I used BL and searched for alternative words to ‘crab’. As it happened, Scorpion was the first alternative I looked for, and the rest is history :)